# How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to set up a complete Python IDE in Sublime Text 2.

I want to know how to run the Python code from within the editor. Is it done using build system? How do I do it ?

Answer (score 380):

Tools -> Build System -> (choose) Python then:

**To Run:**

```
      Tools -> Build

      -or-

      Ctrl + B

      CMD + B  (OSX)
```

*This would start your file in the console which should be at the bottom of the editor.*

**To Stop:**

```
       Ctrl + Break or Tools -> Cancel Build

       Fn + C (OSX)
```

You can find out where your `Break` key is here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key.

Note: `CTRL + C` will **NOT** work.

**What to do when `Ctrl + Break` does not work:**

Go to:

> Preferences -> Key Bindings - User

and paste the line below:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} }
```

Now, you can use `ctrl+shift+c` instead of `CTRL+BREAK`

Comment: sublime text can also "auto detect" the language.  So it worked for me to just CTRL + B

Comment: Make sure `python` is in your `PATH`... the windows installer doesn't seem to do this automagically

Comment: My keyboard's break key looks like "Pause/Break", so to stop process I also added `{"keys": ["pause"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} }`

Comment: Having the line `{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} }` in User key bindings and using `ctrl+shift+c` prints that the build is `[Cancelled]` while the program still being run.

Comment: In IDLE you can continue to use the shell your code runs in (to inspect objects, try more code, etc.). How do we do this in Sublime?

Comment: @matiit, it's cool, but how can I process user's input? something like `guessNumber = input if guessNumber > 10: do_something()`?  after I input number, and press enter, sublime console start new line instead of processing `if statement.

Answer (score 56):

Edit %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Python\Python.sublime-build

Change content to:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

change the "c:\python27" part to any version of python you have in your system.

Comment: Pay attention to the double slash in the path, Sublime won't recognize it otherwise!

Comment: Single forward slash also works in place of double backslash on Windows: "C:/Python27/python.exe" (à la Linux and OSX)

Comment: For me the path was %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python\Python.sublime-build

Comment: I don't seem to see the Python folder in Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 56):

On Mac OS X, save your file with a .py extension. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.  It runs in a window below.

[image]

Answer (score 44):

**To RUN** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (answer by [matiit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8552149/985454))

But when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> **does not work**, Sublime Text probably can't find the Python Interpreter. When trying to run your program, see the log and find the reference to Python in path.

```
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\scripts\\test.py']]
[path: ...;C:\Python27 32bit;...]
```

The point is that it tries to run python via command line, the cmd looks like:

```
python -u C:\scripts\test.py
```

If you can't run python from cmd, Sublime Text can't too.
(Try it yourself in cmd, type python in it and run it, python commandline should appear)

## SOLUTION

You can either change the Sublime Text build formula or the System `%PATH%`.

- To set your `%PATH%`:
  **You will need to restart your editor to load new `%PATH%`*

  - Run Command Line* and enter this command: **needs to be run as administrator*
    `SETX /M PATH "%PATH%;<python_folder>"`
    for example: `SETX /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts"`
  - **OR** manually: (preferable)
    Add `;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts` at the end of the string.
    [image: Setting Path in Win7]
- To set the interpreter's path without messing with System `%PATH%` see this answer by [ppy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9607682/985454).

Comment: Sorry but can you explain what is the meaning of option "-u"? I cannot find the list option of command line params to pass together with python.exe.

Comment: @JimRaynor it's unbuffered streams http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258500/significance-of-u-option

Answer (score 6):

If using python 3.x you need to edit the `Python3.sublime-build`

(Preferences > Browse packages > Python 3)

to look like this:

```
{
  "path": "/usr/local/bin",
  "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

*[ This applies to ST3 (Win), not sure about ST2 ]*

To have the output visible in Sublime as another file (+ one for errors), do this:

1. Create a new build system: `Tools > Build Systems > New Build System...`
2. Use the following configuration:

```
    {
        "cmd": ["python.exe", "$file", "1>", "$file_name.__STDOUT__.txt", "2>", "$file_name.__STDERR__.txt"],
        "selector": "source.python",
        "shell": true,
        "working_dir": "$file_dir"
    }
```

3. For your Python file select the above build system configuration file: `Tools > Build Systems > {your_new_build_system_filename}`
4. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>
5. Now, next to your file, e.g. `"file.py"` you'll have `"file.__STDOUT__.py"` and  `"file.__STDERR__.py"` (for errors, if any)
6. If you split your window into 3 columns, or a grid, you'll see the result immediately, without a need to switch panels / windows

Answer (score 3):

In python v3.x you should go to : `Tools->Build System->New Build System`.

Then, it pop up the untitled.sublime-build window in sublime text editor.Enter setting as:

```
{

    "cmd": ["path_to_the_python.exe","-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

To see the path, `Type following in terminal as`:

```
python
>>> import sys
>>>print(sys.executable)
```

You can make more than one Build System but it should default save inside **Packages of Sublime text** with **.sublime-build** extension.

Then, select the new **Build System**  and press `cltr+b` or other based on your os.

Answer (score 2):

Cool U guys, I just found this:

http://ptomato.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/geek-tip-running-python-guis-in-sublime-text-2/

It explains (like one of the answers above) how to edit this **exec.py** in the **default** directory.

I had the problem that my **PYTHON UI APPLICATION** would not start. I commented out the last line from the following snipped:

```
    # Hide the console window on Windows
    startupinfo = None
    if os.name == "nt":
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        #startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

and, taaadaaaa, I could start my app by pressing Ctrl+B. Funny line anyways, uh? And a big **thank you** to whoever wrote that article ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem :

```
> Preferences –> Browse Packages –> Default
```

Open the `exec.py` file, near line 41-42, the code should look like this :

```
for k, v in proc_env.iteritems():
    proc_env[k] = os.path.expandvars(v).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

then delete it or edit it as :

```
try:    
    for k, v in proc_env.iteritems():
        proc_env[k] = os.path.expandvars(v).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
except:
    print 'foobar'
```

Comment: what does it do actually? How does it help?

Comment: @Qwerty He thought the program should handle exceptions so he put the code in a `try` block.

Comment: I tried this. It didn't fix the problem, and it broke the existing behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today. And here is how I managed to run python code in Sublime Text 3:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (for Mac, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) to start build system. It should execute the file now.
2. Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23790095/3522482) to understand how to customise build system.

What you need to do next is replace the content in `Python.sublime-build` to

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
}
```

You can of course further customise it to something that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

seems the Ctrl+Break doesn't work on me, neither the Preference - User...

use keys, Alt → t → c

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Python console via “View/Show console” or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Comment: but it shows the following error :  File ".\exec.py", line 109, in run
  File ".\ntpath.py", line 205, in dirname
  File ".\ntpath.py", line 170, in split
  File ".\ntpath.py", line 125, in splitdrive
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: Please give more details (by expanding the question) on what you are doing.

Comment: i just type in python code like print 'hello' and then build it and open the console to see this error.

Comment: Using the Python console [does not answer the question](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/basic_concepts.html). The embedded interpreter is intended only to interact with the plugin API, not for general development.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You probably haven't saved the file yet. Make sure to save your code with .py extension and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note about the aforementioned [build system](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html): you can write (and use) custom `.sublime-build` files or even per project `build_systems` clause (in your project settings). This allows you to do useful things like [a fancy test runner with ANSI colors output](https://github.com/aziz/SublimeANSI/issues/1#issuecomment-94841695).

For even more "full IDE" features, you can use the excellent [SublimePythonIDE](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimePythonIDE) package:

- code completion (intel)
- jump to definition & object description
- proper linting/pep8
- supports different interpreters with virtualenv

Disclosure: I've contributed a PR to that package, and I use it all the time, but [there](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI) [are](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18914386/484127).

Answer (score 0):

**Use a real python console alongside Sublime**

Both Sublime's build system and SublimeREPL (the answers above) are limited in that you can't easily interact with the workspace variables after you run your file.

If you want to run a script, then work in a REPL-like fashion (like you would in an IDE), then I recommend having Sublime open alongside an IPython console. Using AutoHotKey (Windows) or AutoKey (Linux), you can set this up such that a single shortcut will copy the filename (or just the selected code) and then paste this in the console to run the file.

Detailed instructions for [Linux](https://gist.github.com/hugke729/90f7eab25c9566bd885a9c25e080efb7) or [Windows](https://gist.github.com/hugke729/5e4c74fa85572b4bb825cc7610592a2d)