# Change python interpreter - Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I just started using Sublime Text 2 and was wondering, to sort of make it a full featured python IDE, if there was a way to change the integrated python interpreter to target the system python install rather than the one that came with Sublime. The reason is because I would like to use my python libraries that I have on my computer with the python interpreter.

I am aware of running python code in sublime using my version of python as explicitly shown here: [How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2)

However, this does not change the version of the python interpreter that you are running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tools > Build System > New Build System. Insert the file and with your python version:

```json
{
  "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said, with python version `["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python"` since I have many python version :(, when I try to run the program on shell, it runs fine, but with sublime, I see `print soup.prettify()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in position 6231: ordinal not in range(128)`, My code is `#! /usr/bin/env python


import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.fp)
print soup.prettify()
`

Comment: To get the above advice to work on OS X I needed to add a symbolic link into `usr/bin` to the location of my Python 3.3 installation. Like this: `sudo ln -s "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3" ./usr/bin/python3`

Comment: I'm not sure why and maybe someone else can clear it up for me, but when I put "python2" where it says "python3", the build system did not work. Changing "python3" to "C:\\Python27\\python.exe" did work for me however.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation referenced by the Sublime Text website itself, the embedded Python intrepreter is [not intended for general development](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#your-system-s-python-vs-the-sublime-text-3-embedded-python). This restricted usage recommendation even applies to ST2 for OS X, which is the only version that *does* use the [system's Python version](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/sublime-text-2/basic_concepts.html#your-system-s-python-vs-the-sublime-text-embedded-python). So it's probably better to use the Build System workflow, or use a ST plug-in. Or switch to a purpose-built IDE.