# Where is the Python interpreter that Sublime Text uses to run plugins?

Tags: python, virtualenv, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to locate the Python interpreter that Sublime Text uses to run plugins.

Thinking that `sys.executable` would give me an absolute path to a Python interpreter, I tried creating this plugin:

```
from sys import version_info, executable    
from sublime_plugin import TextCommand

class GetPythonInfo(TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        print(executable)
        print(version_info)
```

Output in Sublime console:

```
>>> view.run_command('get_python_info')
python3
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=3, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Since I don't have Python 3.3.3 installed elsewhere on my system, I assume that this interpreter was installed as part of Sublime somewhere. Is there a way to run this interpreter outside of Sublime, and if so, how?

There have been some questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313131/change-python-interpreter-sublime-text-2)) asking how to change the Python interpreter for the purposes of the build system. By contrast, I want to build a virtualenv specifically for Sublime plugin development. Ideally, this virtualenv would be based on the Python 3.3.3 interpreter that Sublime uses internally.

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Mac OS X, but I'd be interested in answers for other systems/versions of Sublime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sublime's Python interpreter is compiled into the Sublime executable itself, so there is no way to run it outside of the program. What you *can* do is install the [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) package and run the Sublime REPL to have a little better access to the built-in interpreter.