# Can't execute build (Ctrl + B) in Sublime Text 2 .py file

Tags: python, linux, build, sublimetext2, xubuntu

I'll try to explain the best I can because my English isn't very good.
I am working with Python and Sublime Text 2. Everything worked well, I could build all my .py files without any problem. I was using the default compiler in my Linux distro (Ubuntu 12.04.1), that is Python 2.7.

1 week ago, I discovered I could have Python 3 installed without any trouble an decided to install it. In the shell everything worked fine, if i write the command python it executes the 2.7 version, for the 3.0 I had to write the command Python 3. I made a new build for Python 2 and 3 and it worked.

But one or two days later, I discovered that I only can build the files that are located on the local drive but those that I have in another partition (/media/Data/..) cannot. I just press Ctrl+B or click the command and the build results console doesn't even appear. I removed my build for Python 3 and it stopped working.

Someone knows how to fix it? Because I have all my projects in the other partition and its a little crazy to work this way.

Thank you.

Comment: Post your build for python3, it probably contains invalid syntax somewhere.

Comment: I think it is explained here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2