# Python Builds Systems not working at all. What is the issue?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I keep getting this error, after editing the default build system itself and making new ones.

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'C:\\python32\\python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Ishmael\\Desktop\\projectone.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Ishmael\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Sony\VAIO Improvement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool]
[Finished]
```

In the 'cmd: " I am complete redoing the build but it keeps saving the past builds into itself. (after I apparently override it) Please help, as I just want to build in Sublime Text 2. Running Windows 8.

UPDATE: Forgot the main part, the code. This is what my python.sublime-build currently is.

```
{
   "cmd": ["C:\\python32\\python", "-u", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Do you see what I mean by it keeps adding on the old "c/users/ishmael/etc"? wtf.

Answer (score 1):

Per [How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2), try making sure that the cmd is specified with the full pathname to the interpreter, *including the `.exe` extension*:

```
c:\\python32\\python.exe
```

(assuming your Python interpreter really is at `c:\python32`.

Comment: @Veggies - You're still missing the **.exe**.