# Sublime text 2 build tools - nothing happens

Tags: build, sublimetext2, build-tools

I've tried to use sublime text 2 to write lua\corona program, but I've faced with a problem.

When i add a build tool with such a text:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/Corona Labs/Corona SDK/Corona Simulator.exe", "main.lua"]
}
```

After `F7` or `ctrl+b` or build button in menu - only blank small window shows and "Building" text appears on bottom of the window - nothing else happen (even when I try to check other available build tools).

I even try to put other commands in "cmd" - this blank field on the bottom of sublime still blank and this simulator doesn't appear (if I write in command line "C:/Program Files/Corona Labs/Corona SDK/Corona Simulator.exe" simulator starts).

**UPDATE**

I've opened console and there is some log:

```
Running C:/Program Files/Corona Labs/Corona SDK/Corona Simulator.exe main.lua
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File ".\exec.py", line 154, in run
  File ".\exec.py", line 45, in __init__
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this : http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8512

In `Packages/Default/exec.py` at line 45

Replace :

```
proc_env[k] = os.path.expandvars(v).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

With :

```
os.path.expandvars(v.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```