# Sublime Text 2 buiding C++ - nothing happens

Tags: build, sublimetext2, build-tools

Trying to build a C++ file using Sublime's console I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File "./exec.py", line 130, in run
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0301' in position 78: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I already read this: [Sublime text 2 build tools - nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715918/sublime-text-2-build-tools-nothing-happens), but after fixing that one I got another error you see above.

Any hints on making this work (allow me to build and run simple C++ codes directly from ST2) would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing your build file and some sample code you are trying to compile/run.

Comment: My build file is the standard one from Sublime Text 2 (fresh download). Any C++ code will fail, no matter what is inside.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

- [Sublime Text 2 encoding error with python3 build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166076/sublime-text-2-encoding-error-with-python3-build)

I'm using *Sublime **3*** and it does build simple files (like "hello world") without any problem (using **CTRL+B** or **CTRL+SHIFT+B**). I have Windows 8.1, 64 bits.

Comment: The link you provided is about an error when building Python and not C++. I tried it anyway, but sadly it did not fix the problem. I am interested in running ST2.

Comment: My idea is to focus on the error message instead the language. 

ps.: Sorry, I forgot that I could post comments (because low rep). I didn't think this was a properly answer, but I wanted to share with you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you're trying to run a program that contains the ´ (acute accent) character. Either that's a mistake and you intended to write the single quote ' instead, or if that's what you wanted, then the Python interpreter does not recognise as an ASCII char (since it isn't) and thus complains.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I am sorry to say this is not the case. Any code fails. Pasted from anywhere, written from scratch, checked for hidden characters.