# Printing not being logged by Kubernetes

Tags: python, logging, kubernetes, python-2.x, kubectl

I have simple python 2.7 program running in container off Kubernetes (AKS) which is printing debug information to standard output

```
response = requests.post(uri,data=body, headers=headers)
if (response.status_code >= 200 and response.status_code <= 299):
    print 'Accepted ' + log_type + ' on ' + rfc1123date
else:
    print "Response code: {}".format(response.status_code)
```

I don't see it with `kubectl logs container_name`, output is empty (but I know it is fine because of successful post). I tried to add `"-u"` to `CMD ["-u","syslog2la.py"]` in Dockerfile, but it didn't help. How to get the python print in '*kubectl logs*'?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the following to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
```

Comment: As a sidenote, you can also start python with the '-u' flag for unbuffered output. E.g. /bin/python3 -u /path/to/script.py

Comment: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` worked for me. `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0` did not.

Comment: 0 does not work and 1 does. Recommend this answer removed or clarified with further evidence and context why 0 is also acceptable. Same comment regarding 1 as well. The explanation is needed why 0 or 1 is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

credit to @frederix

Comment: Not sure if this is version-based but running python 3.11 I needed this rather than the `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0` suggested by the  approved answer

Answer (score 2):

Guide for understanding the PYTHONUNBUFFERED magic:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Python by default writes to stdout using a buffer, which k8s can't handle - it waits for the buffer to close before it will read data from it, and it is always open from the Python side.

Therefore, you need to tell python do not use the buffer, by setting ENV var before the application start.

There is also an opposite option, called "PYTHONBUFFERED".

This means these options are equivalent:

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

```
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=0
```

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Also this is possible: 
Just replace `all print` with `sys.stderr.write()`

Example:

```py
import sys

print(out_text)
sys.stderr.write(out_text + "\n")
```

Notice to `\n` at the end.