# Call a function everytime logging module in python is called

Tags: python, logging, wrapper

I would like to call a function everytime, I do any sort of logging using the `logging` module in python.

As can be seen below, instead of calling `copyfiles` at each instance of logging, I would like to see if there is way to injest copyfiles to the filehandler in someway or even a wrapper.

```
from sys import argv
import shutil
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('')

sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logfile = 'logs/log-run-{}.log'.format(date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
fh = logging.FileHandler(logfile)

formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s \
                            [%(filename)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] \
                            %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

sh.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(sh)
logger.addHandler(fh)

LOGPATH = args[1]
def copyfiles():
    """
    Copy files to azure blob storage
    """
    fh.flush()
    shutil.copy(logfile, LOGPATH)

logging.info('test')
copyfiles()
logging.info('foobar')
copyfiles()
```

I tried digging into invoking copyfiles each time logging is called, but I ended up no where.

In case you are wondering why I am copy files from logging, [this is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579648/periodic-stdout-and-stderr-from-azure-batch-service/66587355#66587355).

Comment: So you want to copy the whole file every time a new line is added to it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I have suggested a solution, let me know if that would work. Just curious, wouldn't this cause a ton of extra File I/O's and become a bottleneck ?

Comment: This might become a bottleneck, but this is the only way out as stdout and stderr aren't given until the end of the job. so, i don't even know what i am waiting for

Comment: I really think this is a very bad idea. Why not using another handler like an HTTPHandler, a SocketHandler, a DatagramHandler, whatever?

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how to incorporate it inside azure batch service?

Comment: (I want to note that I would like to use this only in debug mode, and definetly NOT in production mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this is what I could think of:

- Override the flush() of FileHandler by inheriting it into a utility
  class like FlushCopyFileHandler class shown in the code below.
- Instead of using the FileHandler use the FlushCopyFileHandler class
  and all you have to do is call this overridden flush().

"""

```
from logging import FileHandler
from shutil

class FlushCopyFileHandler(FileHandler):
    
    # These arguments are passed along to the parent class FileHandler.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FlushCopyFileHandler, self).__init__(filename, *args, **kwargs)
        self.copy_destination = "some default destination path"   # can also be set from args.
        
    # When this flush() is called it will call the flush() of FileHandler class.
    # After that it will call the shutil.copy() method.
    def flush(self):
        super().flush()
        shutil.copy(self.filename, self.copy_destination)
        
    # Use this to change destination path later on.
    def set_copy_path(self, destination):
        self.copy_destination = destination
```

"""