# SLURM batch script doesn't execute Python script, returns no error message and doesn't stop running

Tags: python, slurm

In a SLURM cluster I am submitting a shell script that calls a python script (both scripts can be found below. When the shell script executes it get until where the python script is called but then nothing happens: there is no output, no error message and the SLURM job keeps running.

I assume the entire contents of the python script are not relevant (but I included it anyway for completion). For debugging purposes I inserted the `print("script started")` line at the very beginning to see if it gets run but it doesn't. The last thing I see in the output is `moved to directory`.

I tried calling a `test.py` script containing `print("test")`right before this and it gets executed normally.

What could be the reason the python script doesn't start and how can I fix it?

Edit: As user jakub recommended changing `print("script started")`to `print("script started", flush=True)`successfully gets printed. Including several more of these statements revealed that the script was actually running perfectly fine, it just didn't output anything. Including the same statement within the for loop that gets constantly executed also makes all `print()` statements previously missing get printed.

The question then turns into: why do the `print()` statements here need to have `flush=True` in this script but not in other scripts?

Shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --mail-user=lukas.baehler@pathology.unibe.ch
#SBATCH --mail-type=end,fail
#SBATCH --output=out-ncl
#SBATCH --error=err-ncl
#SBATCH --job-name="Mask RCNN nucleus training and detection"

#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=gpu
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=64G

#SBATCH --gres=gpu:gtx1080ti:1
#SBATCH --constraint=rtx2080


conda init bash
source ~/.bashrc
conda activate nucl

cd MRCNN/samples/nucleus
echo "moved to directory"

python nucleus-pipeline2.py splitTMA
echo "Split TMAs"
```

Python script:

```py
print("script started")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    import os

    # Copied from later in script because the argparse part was moved up and is
    # needed as default in --logs.
    ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("../../")
    DEFAULT_LOGS_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "logs")

    # Parse command line arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Mask R-CNN for nuclei counting and segmentation')
    parser.add_argument("command",
                        metavar="<command>",
                        help="'splitTMA', 'splitSpot', 'structure', 'train' or 'detect'")
    parser.add_argument('--dataset', required=False,
                        metavar="/path/to/dataset/",
                        help='Root directory of the dataset')
    parser.add_argument('--weights', required=False,
                        metavar="/path/to/weights.h5",
                        help="Path to weights .h5 file or 'coco'")
    parser.add_argument('--logs', required=False,
                        default=DEFAULT_LOGS_DIR,
                        metavar="/path/to/logs/",
                        help='Logs and checkpoints directory (default=logs/)')
    parser.add_argument('--subset', required=False,
                        metavar="Dataset sub-directory",
                        help="Subset of dataset to run prediction on")

    # Own arguments
    parser.add_argument("--input", required=False,
                        metavar="path/to/input/folder",
                        help="Optionally specify the input directory. Should only be used with splitTMA, splitSpot and structure.")
    parser.add_argument("--output", required=False,
                        metavar="path/to/output/folder",
                        help="Optionally specify the output directory. Should only be used with splitTMA, splitSpot and structure.")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    assert args.command in ["train", "detect", "splitTMA", "splitSpot", "structure"], "Must set command."




    ################################################################################
    # splitTMA
    ################################################################################


    # The original script for this is tma-spot.py
    # Splits a TMA into images of its spots.
    if args.command == "splitTMA":


        import os
        import cv2
        import numpy as np
        from openslide import open_slide
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


        ###################
        # CONFIGURATION

        # Defines the level of resolution for spot recognition
        level = 7 # Default 7

        # Defines the level of resolution to use for the new images
        newLevel = 0 # Default 0 (higest resolution)

        # Defines the spot size in pixels (has to be changed if newLevel is changed)
        SpotSize = 3072 # Default 3500

        # # Shift values are for alignment of the two slides.
        # shiftX = 445 - 10
        # shiftY = -64 + 10

        print("Using the following parameters:\nlevel = {}\nnewLevel = {}\nSpotSize = {}".format(level, newLevel, SpotSize))
        ###################


        # NUCLEUS_DIR = "MRCNN/samples/nucleus"
        NUCLEUS_DIR = os.path.abspath("")
        os.chdir(NUCLEUS_DIR)

        if args.input:
            INPUT_DIR = args.input
        else:
            INPUT_DIR = "slides"
        print("Using '{}' as input folder.".format(INPUT_DIR))

        if args.output:
            OUTPUT_DIR = args.output
        else:
            OUTPUT_DIR = "spots"
        print("Using '{}' as output folder.".format(OUTPUT_DIR))

        # mrxs_filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir("slides") if filename[-5:] == ".mrxs"]
        mrxs_filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(INPUT_DIR) if filename[-5:] == ".mrxs"]
        print("\nFound {} MIRAX files.".format(len(mrxs_filenames)))

        # Loop through all .mrxs files.
        for filename in mrxs_filenames:

            print("\nReading {}\n".format(filename))

            # filename = mrxs_filenames[0]
            img = open_slide("{}/{}".format(INPUT_DIR, filename))

            # # Use if you want to to see the resolution of all the levels.
            # for i in range(img.level_count):
            #     print("Level", i, "dimension", img.level_dimensions[i],"down factor",img.level_downsamples[i])

            # Use the level set previously and read the slide as an RGB image.
            x_img = img.read_region((0,0), level, img.level_dimensions[level])
            x_img = np.array(x_img)
            rgb = np.zeros_like(x_img)
            rgb[x_img==0] = 255
            rgba_im = cv2.add(rgb,x_img)
            imgLevel = cv2.cvtColor(rgba_im,cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
            # plt.imsave("./Output/level" + str(level) + ".png", imgLevel) # <---------- USE FOR DEBUGGING

            # Converts the image to gray levels and applies a gussian blur.
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgLevel, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            gray_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
            # cv2.imwrite( "./Output/gray.png", gray_blur) # <-------------------------- USE FOR DEBUGGING

            # Use an Otsu binarization to generate a mask for where tissue is.
            ret3, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_blur, 8, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
            thresh = ~thresh
            cont_img = thresh.copy()
            # cv2.imwrite( "spots/cd3/contour.png", cont_img) # <------------------------ USE FOR DEBUGGING

            # Finds the contours of the mask generated.
            contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(cont_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            # Loop through all contours
            spot_nr = 0
            for cnt in contours:

                # Decide based on the area of the contour if it is a spot
                area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                spotInfo = []
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                if area < 100 or area > 2000:
                    spotInfo.append([-1, x, y, w, h])
                    continue
                if len(cnt) < 5:
                    spotInfo.append([-1, x, y, w, h])
                    continue

                # Calculate the center of the spot
                centerX = x + int(w/2)
                centerY = y + int(h/2)

                # Calculate how much it needs to be scaled
                factorOld = img.level_downsamples[level]
                factorNew = img.level_downsamples[newLevel]

                # Read the spot region
                spot = img.read_region((int(centerX * factorOld)-int(SpotSize/2),
                                        int(centerY * factorOld)-int(SpotSize/2)),
                                        newLevel, (SpotSize, SpotSize))
                spot = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(spot), cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

                # Create directory and save the image
                if not os.path.isdir("{}/{}".format(OUTPUT_DIR, filename[:-5])):
                    os.makedirs("{}/{}".format(OUTPUT_DIR, filename[:-5]))
                spot_name =  "{0}/{1}/{1}-{2}.png".format(OUTPUT_DIR, filename[:-5],str(spot_nr).zfill(3))
                plt.imsave(spot_name, spot)
                spot_nr += 1

                print("Spot {} saved - Center X and Y: {}, {}".format(spot_nr, centerX, centerY))
        exit()



    ################################################################################
    # splitSpot
    ################################################################################


    # This is copied from spot-annotation.py
    # Splits spots into tiles
    if args.command == "splitSpot":

        import os
        import sys
        import argparse

        import re
        import numpy as np
        import cv2
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


        # VARIABLES

        # Change the resolution of the tiles here. Note the image resolution
        # must be an integer multiple of the tile resolutions (both dimensions).
        tile_resolution = [768, 768]

        # NUCLEUS_DIR = "MRCNN/samples/nucleus"
        NUCLEUS_DIR = os.path.abspath("")
        os.chdir(NUCLEUS_DIR)

        if args.input:
            INPUT_DIR = args.input
        else:
            INPUT_DIR = "spots"
        print("\nUsing '{}' as input folder.".format(INPUT_DIR))

        if args.output:
            OUTPUT_DIR = args.output
        else:
            OUTPUT_DIR = "tiles"
        print("Using '{}' as output folder.".format(OUTPUT_DIR))


        # EXECUTION

        TMA_folders = os.listdir(INPUT_DIR)
        spot_names = []
        spot_count = 0
        for name in TMA_folders:
            spot_names.append(os.listdir("{}/{}".format(INPUT_DIR, name)))
            spot_count += len(spot_names[-1])
        print("\nFound {} TMA folders with a total of {} spot images.".format(len(TMA_folders), spot_count))


        for a, TMA in enumerate(TMA_folders):
            for b, spot in enumerate(spot_names[a]):

                print("TMA: {}/{} - Spot: {}/{}".format(a+1, len(TMA_folders), b+1, len(spot_names[a])), end="\r")


                # Read the image
                img = cv2.imread("{}/{}/{}".format(INPUT_DIR,TMA, spot))

                # Calculate how many tiles will be produced
                tilesX = img.shape[0]/tile_resolution[0]
                tilesY = img.shape[1]/tile_resolution[1]
                assert (tilesX == int(tilesX) and tilesY == int(tilesY)), "Image resolution is not an integer multiple of the tile resolution."
                tilesX, tilesY = int(tilesX), int(tilesY)

                # Create the np array that will hold the tiles
                tiles = np.zeros([tilesY,tilesX,tile_resolution[0],tile_resolution[1],3])

                # Loop through all tiles and store them in tiles
                for i in range(tilesX):
                    for j in range(tilesY):
                        tiles[j,i] = img[i*tile_resolution[0]:(i+1)*tile_resolution[0],
                                        j*tile_resolution[1]:(j+1)*tile_resolution[1]]

                tiles = tiles.astype("uint8")

                # print("\nImage was split into {} tiles.".format(tiles.shape[0]*tiles.shape[1]))

                # Save all the tiles
                for x in range(tiles.shape[0]):
                    for y in range(tiles.shape[1]):
                        # Displays progression
                        # print("Saving {}/{} images...".format(str(x*tiles.shape[0]+y+1),tiles.shape[0]*tiles.shape[1]), end="\r")

                        # Using the plt.imsave() gives alterations in color which is
                        # presumably bad. Using cv2.imwrite() is also ca. 10 times faster.
                        imdir = "{}/{}/{}".format(OUTPUT_DIR, TMA, spot[:-4])
                        imname = "{}-{}-{}.png".format(spot[:-4], str(x).zfill(2), str(y).zfill(2))
                        if not os.path.isdir(imdir):
                            os.makedirs(imdir)


                        cv2.imwrite("{}/{}".format(imdir, imname), tiles[x,y])

        print("\nSaved images in {} as [spot_name]-x-y.png.".format(OUTPUT_DIR))
        exit()



    ################################################################################
    # Prepare Data Structure
    ################################################################################


    # Adapted from prepare-data-structure.py
    # Creates the data structure required for the network
    if args.command == "structure":

        import os
        from shutil import copyfile

        NUCLEUS_DIR = os.path.abspath("")
        os.chdir(NUCLEUS_DIR)

        # Setting input and output directories
        if args.input:
            INPUT_DIR = args.input
        else:
            INPUT_DIR = "tiles"
        print("\nUsing '{}' as input folder.".format(INPUT_DIR))

        if args.output:
            OUTPUT_DIR = args.output
        else:
            OUTPUT_DIR = "data"
        print("Using '{}' as output folder.".format(OUTPUT_DIR))

        # Creates a list with the paths of all tiles. Also stores just the
        # filename itself with and without file extension
        file_names = []
        for path,_,files in os.walk(INPUT_DIR):
            for f in files:
                file_names.append(["{}/{}".format(path, f), f, f[:-4]])
        print("\nFound {} images.".format(len(file_names)))

        assert file_names != [], "No images found in input folder."

        # The dataset needs to be stored inside another folder (default "own_data")
        subset = "own_data"

        # For each file creates the appropriate sub-folders and copies the file.
        skip_count = 0
        for i,info in enumerate(file_names):
            print("Saving {}/{} images.".format(i+1, len(file_names)), end="\r")
            dirname = "{}/{}/{}/images".format(OUTPUT_DIR, subset, info[2])
            try:
                os.makedirs(dirname)
            except:
                skip_count += 1
                continue
            copyfile(info[0], "{}/{}".format(dirname, info[1]))


        print("\n\nSaved dataset in {}/{}".format(OUTPUT_DIR, subset))
        if skip_count > 0:
            print("Skipped {} files because they already existed.".format(skip_count))
        print("")
        exit()
```

Comment: This could be something to do with the buffer `print` uses. Can you try `print("script started", flush=True)`? By the way, you shouldn't have to run `conda init bash ... source ~/.bashrc` in your sbatch script. You can run those interactively outside of the job before submitting the script, and you only need to run them once.

Comment: Yes this gets printed. I've included a bunch more of these throughout the code and found that the script actually runs perfectly fine but just doesn't print anything. But why then does nothing get printed unless I use `flush=True`? (I'll also update the question itself. As for the conda init bash...: Whenever I don't include it, it gives me an error message that I should use it so I kept it.

Comment: Also, could you write this as an answer so I can accept it as the answer to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python buffers stdin, stdout, and stderr by default. `print()` writes to `stdout` by default, so you will see this buffered behavior.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/14258511/5666087 :

> Python opens the stdin, -out and -error streams in a buffered mode; it'll read or write in larger chunks, keeping data in memory until a threshold is reached.

You can forcibly flush this buffer by passing `flush=True` to `print`. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more information. If you have multiple `print` statements in a row, you need only use `flush=True` in the last one.