# Can't find python.sublimetbuild in OS X

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

After I installed the sublime text3,there is a python2.7

but I want to use the python3.4.So I need to modify the python.sublimebuild but I can't find it.

Some said it is in preference->Browse Packages ,but I didn't find it here .

[image]

Also I downloaded many Packages and I want to read the readme.md ,but I still can't find it in the "Installed Packages",I can't open the file.

[image]

Could you tell me where is the "sublimebuild" and "read.md"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run sublime
Preferences > Browse packages > Python

then it will bring you to the right folder

e.g. C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23347185/4270657