# execute python in sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

when i build a python programme in sublime text i get

> python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file. [Finished in 1.0s with exit code 1]

[image]

The issue is sublime text can't locate the path where python.
 when i try to do manually put the path i.e `c:\python34\python.exe` I can't go ahead of preferences browse packages as there are no option to select python

How to proceed further what to do

guys for your  clearation i have added the environment variable and python works perfectly fine in cmd..
[image]

this is the complete error i am getting

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Why downvotes someone should upvote it is commonly faced problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it solved thanks to Ben Usman and ha9u63ar what i did was

```
           Tools - Build System - New Build System

 {
"path": "/usr/local/bin",
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "selector": "source.python"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools - Build System - New Build System

```
{
    "cmd": ["path_to_your_python", "$file"]
}
```

than just use this build system.

Comment: by which type we should save this build system file

Comment: `.sublime-build` I guess

Answer (score 0):

Sublime, if you haven't noticed already, is created with Python so you can expect it to have full support for the language. Based on your error, I'd venture to guess that you haven't added Python to your path. Watch the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucx9_OWE6BE) for instructions. Otherwise, you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZpuwW-9T54) video for how to change build configurations.