# How to run a Python program in Sublime Text without using command line

Tags: python, sublimetext

Every tutorial I've gone through has said to run the program through command line is that the only possibility or can I run the program straight from sublime text like you can with TextPad or Visual Studio?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2