# how do you run a function in sublime text 2

Tags: python, function, sublimetext2

I am using sublime text 2 for python and I want to run a function that I made.  So in idle if you want to run a function you just type in the name, function(x,y) and it runs the function after pressing F5.  When I try this in the interpreter, after pressing ctrl b, in sublime it doesn't work, how to I run functions sublime?

Comment: Sublime text is a text editor, you have to look at the software you're developping in a browser (if it's web) or something else. There is no "preview" mode in sublime text 2 by default

Comment: I think, generally, you're looking for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2?rq=1

Comment: If you want to run Python code, *make sure the file is saved first*.

Comment: I did the update that khtad mentioned, and the file is saved.  I have the code def function(x,y)      and the next line is return x+y.  Its not on one line, its in the right format.  Then I go to view\show console.  That shows the interperater at the bottom of the page where you can type.  I typed function(2,2), and I got an error that says :NameError: name 'function is not defined