# Having trouble getting python build working in sublime text 2 (on mac)

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I've been working at this for an hour or so now, just having no luck. It looks to me like it thinks I'm trying to run the code in javascript, and when I use javascript it works. I don't know why my python build is running javascript though. I checked the file and it seems fine.

[what I tried to run, and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7tcF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you specified "Python" via `Tools > Build System > Python`?

See this question: [How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sadly that was all it was, don't I feel stupid, thank you so much!
I even read that question and didn't think to do that somehow, I guess all I had done was select the syntax. Ill mark yours as correct as soon as it lets me.