# Execute Python in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

How can I execute Python 2.7 code using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10? When I use the shortcut `Ctrl+B` it says `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I can't edit python.sublime-build because as far as I know it does not exist in Sublime Text 3.

**EDIT: I see this question is a duplicate. I did not see the post when I searched up the topic for some reason.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2

Comment: Like I said, there is no python.sublime-build.

Comment: Is Python installed on your computer? If not, install it. If so, find it, copy the path to the folder containing `python.exe`, and add that path to your system's `PATH` variable.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. And yes I have python on my computer

Answer (score 3):

You need to add python to your system path or if you already have there is a chance that
that in C:\Windows there is exe with python icon called "py" rename it to "python" and it should work fine.

Comment: I see nothing with py.exe in the Windows folder

Comment: If it's not there, look in `C:` for a `PythonXX` folder

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Nothing there.