# Is is possible to send code from text editor to existing ipython console

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext3

I am starting to learn python with sublime and ipython. They are cool tools and but I want a way to connect them.
I normally have a sublime and a IPython console open. Is there any command that I can run in sublime just send:

```
runfile('~\someExample.py', wdir='~\myDir')
```

to the running IPython console?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2  to run from Sublime, or you can do `exec(open('/path/to/your_file.py').read())` from the iPython command line.

Comment: That link is about running the code in a new python session, not an existing one.

Comment: Did you solve your problem. Want to do the same thing

Comment: @fossekall No... Unfortunately. I haven't figured out a way to even starting a new ipython console and run my codes. I will just stick to spyder.

Answer (score 1):

I edit in `geany` and use, in `ipthon`:

```
run myfile
```

to load and run `myfile.py`.  `ls` and `cd` and `pwd` are available to check and change the directory.

I save the file from the editor, but I control the run from the `ipython` console.

If I just need to run the script, I could do a `python myfile.py` in the editor's terminal window, or maybe via the editor's `execute` shortcut.  But the value in running the code in an existing `ipython` console is that I can interact with the newly loaded code and variables.  I can examine variables, rerun functions with new values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin to do this called [SendCode](https://github.com/randy3k/SendCode); you can install it directly through the package manager.

As another answer mentioned, you can run some set of shell commands from within ipython, including execution of a file with `run python_file.py`, as well as other shell commands including `cd, mkdir, rm, mv`, etc.