# Python 3.x does not convert input() to string in SublimeText editor

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code in SublimeText

```
message = input ("Say something and I will repeat it : ")

print (message)
```

However, when I run it using SublimeREPL it returns that the input isn't defined 
unless I enter it with the customary string quotations. Is there anyway around it? I've read it may be because the interpreter is from python2? Any help.

Comment: That sounds like you're not really on Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

[What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

In Python 2, `raw_input()` returns a string, and `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression.
In Python 3, `raw_input = input`

So yes, the fact that the SublimeREPL interpreter is in Python2 is the cause.
But you can use the Python 3.x interpreter in Sublime, look for it!

Comment: Hello Adrien thanks for that I've been searching but so far no luck, could you point me in the right direction perhaps?

Comment: Depending on which plateform you are, it can differ. But everything is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2 (see ppy answer)