# Python: How To Run A Terminal To Read Emails In Sublime?

Tags: python, email

I am following a tutorial and with that code below he clicks on F5 and on the terminal it appears

```
=============== RESTART:c:Users/Samuel/Documents/IMAP Python Email.py ==========================
```

See image
[image]
How do I launch a terminal like that in Sublime?

```
# the file is called IMAP Python Email.py stored in C:/Users/Samuel/Documents/IMAP Python Email.py(3.6.0)

import imaplib, email
user = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'

con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user,password)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2)

Comment: When I click CTRL+B it doesn't run a terminal, it only says [Finished in 1.7s]

Comment: There's more than one answer to that question. Have you tried all of them?