# Adding whitespace to strings in Text editor

Tags: python, whitespace, sublimetext, strip

I am a newbie to Python, and my question is therefore maybe a little silly.

But I still want to know if it is possible to do the same thing in "Text Editor", like in the "Terminal" - in theory, it should be possible!!

My question is about a variable like:
***famous_people ="   Albert Einstein   "***   ,

you write print(famous_people) or just famous_people and press enter.

The result will show as   **'   Albert Einstein   '**

If then want to remove the space between the quotations marks you ten write the following,

**famous_people.strip()** and the result will be,

**'Albert Einstein'**

How do you do the same thing in "Sublime text" or another text editor. ???

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in Sublime?

Comment: you could use [build tools](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html) to run your code on this text editor, I would recommend read: [How do I run Python code from Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551735/how-do-i-run-python-code-from-sublime-text-2)